# fatal error: seal/seal.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, seal

i am a newbie to cmake and microsoft seals, when i am trying to add seal library to my project using cmake i get error as follows:

> PS D:\vHHE_test> cmake --build build
> MSBuild version 17.9.5+33de0b227 for .NET Framework
>
> 1>Checking Build System
> Building Custom Rule D:/vHHE_test/CMakeLists.txt
> main.cpp
> D:\vHHE_test\main.cpp(2,9): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'seal/seal.h': No such file or > > directory [D:\vHHE_test\build\hello.vcxproj]

I followed Microsoft seal's instructions:

```
cmake -S . -B build -DSEAL_ROOT=D:\\SEAL\\native\\src\\seal
cmake --build build
```

Below is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(hello)
set(SEAL_ROOT ${SEAL_ROOT}) 
include_directories(${SEAL_ROOT})
add_executable(hello main.cpp)
```

I look forward to receiving help from everyone

I would like to find a solution that will help me declare the seal library and run my project without errors

Comment: When you include `seal/seal.h` you're looking for `D:/SEAL/native/src/seal/seal/seal.h` ... Is that actually correct? Noting the extra `/seal/` directory

Comment: Edit the official instructions are here: [https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL?tab=readme-ov-file#linking-with-microsoft-seal-through-cmake](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL?tab=readme-ov-file#linking-with-microsoft-seal-through-cmake) `find_package(SEAL 4.1 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(<your target> SEAL::seal)` is what Microsoft says to do in the documentation link.

Comment: @ChrisMM thanks for your help,I don't have too much experience in programming.Can I ask one more question? when i run `cmake --build build` it return error about syntax problems in the source code `D:\SEAL\native\src\seal\version.h(30,22): error C2059: syntax error: ';'`, I also found a report about the same problem on the seal but haven't found the answer I needed

Comment: Look at line 30 of version.h like it told you to see if you can spot a misplaced `;`